# Netbeans installation doesn't find JDK

Tags: java, netbeans

installing Netbeans 6.0.1 on my windows computer, I find this error:

[image]

Even if I my enviroment variables seems to be ok, when executing:
[image]

I rebooted my system, but the error persists. Does anybody know why??
Thans in advance

Comment: NetBeans 6.0.1 is extremely old. Did you try the current version? (which is 6.9.1)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are certain that you have a **JDK** installed (and not a JRE), you can specify the location of the JDK on the commandline when starting the installer (as mentioned in the error message you get).

These FAQ entries might also help you:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqInstallJavahome
http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSuitableJvmNotFound

Comment: I managed to fix it using this link: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqRunningOnJre
Step 2 did it for me, changing the JDK location to the one I had it installed under instead of some jre location in the netbeans folder itself.

Answer (score 36):

This is only due to javahome path missing.

**Use the command line below:--**

For Windows OS- Open your command prompt

```
netbeans-6.5.1-windows.exe --javahome "C:\\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0"
```

For Linux OS- Open your Terminal

```
netbeans-6.5.1-windows.sh --javahome /usr/jdk/jdk1.6.0_04
```

The problem solved.

Comment: This is working and easy.... Thank you..(just change the paths relatively )

Comment: Oh I had to write double minus not just single minus lol... what a stupid tutorial from installer

Comment: Good man, thank you

Comment: Still works. I just tried it using `Java19` and `Netbeans16`. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Set `JAVA_HOME` in environment variable.

set `JAVA_HOME` to only `JDK1.6.0_23` or whatever `jdk folder` you have. dont include `bin` folder in path.

Comment: and should I include JAVA_HOME variable into PATH?? Anyway, I tryed it and is still the same error. Thansk

Comment: @mujer: set `JAVA_HOME` in environment variable of windows so every app can access it.

Comment: this answer helped me

Answer (score 7):

Set the JAVA_HOME variable as noted above, but also set the JRE_HOME variable to the Java Runtime Environment folder (example: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\jre )

To set the windows environment variable, right click on My Computer and select "Properties" and choose the "Advanced" tab on older windows versions, or click the "Advanced system settings" link on new versions of windows. Click the "Environment Variables" button and, in the System Variables section, click the "New" button and add the above variable names and enter the appropriate filesystem paths as the values.

After you've installed Netbeans, check the following:

Open C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 6.0.1\etc\netbeans.conf

Change this value to the location of your JDK folder if it isn't set correctly already:

netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_23"

Comment: i dont think `JRE_HOME` is required to be set only `JAVA_HOME` will be enough.

Comment: Most computers have the JRE installed and not the JDK, most Java installers will look for the JRE.

Comment: yes you are right but if you are a java developer than it becomes necessary to have JDK installed on your development machine.

Comment: @Harry: Obviously, but Java programs, including the Netbeans installer look for the JRE by default, not the JDK.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

We managed installation of netbeans 6.8 under windows 8 successfully the following way:

- Don't execute but unzip netbeans-6.8-ml-windows.exe with 7zip (or other unzipper) in an emtpy folder
- execute cmd.exe as administrator
- cd to the folder in which you unzipped the installer
- execute 'java org.netbeans.installer.Installer'

-> installation executes without any errors

Comment: I have successfully installed NetBeans. Thanks! Is there a similar way to uninstall as well? Because now the uninstaller is not detecting the JDK.

Comment: This worked for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem. So I tried by installing a lesser version say jdk1.5 and running the netbeans installation from command prompt as:
Linux: netbeans-5_5-linux.bin -is:javahome /usr/jdk/jdk1.5.0_06
Windows: netbeans-5_5-windows.exe -is:javahome "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_06"

Hope it helps