# How to work on UAC when installing XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

I am installing Xampp to my computer but when i tried to install it a dialog box is showing up. how do i fix this one.. thank you so much for the help.! the dialog Box:

> Important! Because an activated User Account Control (UAC) on your system some
> functions of XAMPP are possibly restricted.
>
> With UAC please avoid to install XAMPP
> to C:\Program Files(Missing Write permissions). Or Deactivate UAC with msconfig after
> this setup.

Comment: It means don't install it to program files because it needs write permissions to its install directory.

Comment: *Do not deactivate UAC.*  Instead, install XAMPP to a different directory besides C:\Program Files.  You can easily install XAMPP to the root of your C: drive and not have any problems.  Or even better, if you have a drive without an OS on it, install it there.

Answer (score 67):

This is a specific issue for Windows Vista, 7, 8 (and presumably newer).

User Account Control (UAC) is a feature in Windows that can help you stay in control of your computer by informing you when a program makes a change that requires administrator-level permission. UAC works by adjusting the permission level of your user account.

This is applied mostly to C:\Program Files. You may have noticed sometimes, that some applications can see files in C:\Program Files that does not exist there. You know why? Windows now tend to have "C:\Program Files" folder customized for every user. For example, old applications store config files (like .ini) in the same folder where the executable files are stored. In the good old days all users had the same configurations for such apps. In nowadays Windows stores configs in the special folder tied to the user account. Thus, now different users may have different configs while application still think that config files are in the same folder with the executables.

XAMPP does not like to have different config for different users. In fact it is not a config file for XAMPP, it is folders where you keep your projects and databases. The idea of XAMPP is to make projects same for all users. This is a source of a conflict with Windows.

**All you need is to avoid installing XAMPP into C:\Program Files.** Thus XAMPP will always use the original files for all users and there would be no confusion.

**I recommend to install XAMPP into the special folder in root directory like in C:\XAMPP. But before you choose the folder you need to click  on this warning message.**

Comment: yeah well that is nice and all . . . but I still get the UAC warnings EVERY TIME I USE IT.

Comment: Well, don't use it. Use Vagrant or Docker boxes. I use [homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead). It is amazing, it comes with ngnix and apache and all versions of php and mySQL and postgreSql, and you can configure what to use in one file. And you even can make multiple environment for many projects at one config file. It works for windows too. And I even have answered a question of how to make it faster :)

Answer (score 16):

You can press **OK** and install **xampp** to **C:\xampp** and not into **program files**

Answer (score 6):

You can press **ok** and it will continue the insallation.

Otherwise, see  [Trying to reinstall XAMPP on windows 7, getting error messag](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=176593&sid=dd6003b4b4692e7f367989a56224c0a3)...

Answer (score 5):

Basically there's three things you can do

1. Ensure that your user account has administrator privilege.
2. Disable User Account Control (UAC).
3. Install in C://xampp.

I've writen an answer to a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58841776/5675325) where explain how you can disable UAC since Windows 8.

Comment: it installs on 3. by default (in  C://xampp). Good explanation! Thanks

Comment: Still after installing it, when I close it, says: "Error: cannot create file C:\xampp\xampp-control.ini. Access is denied"

Exception EAccess Violation in module xampp-control.exe at ____ ; Access violation at address ___ in module xampp.control.exe" Read of adddress ____ .

Comment: this helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676374/xampp-control-panel-shows-an-error-upon-launch

Basically I ran as admin. 

Sorry for the spam, hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Thank you for sharing that also @JessicaPereira.

Answer (score 3):

To disable UAC go to
Start>Control Panel>User Accounts
there you will find an option
Turn User Account Control on or off
just click on it and uncheck
User Account Control to help protect your computer
click OK.

Please refer to this link : https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=45364

Answer (score 2):

It's not all about the permissions!
If you have already installed any application which has one(or more) running service(s) that using ports 80 and 443, then you will face the problem anytime you try to start the Apache.
For example, if you are using a VMWare workstation that would be a serious problem!
I couldn't get any proper result by changing XAMPP's config files.
So in this case, I tried to reconfigure the VMWARE or stop a specific windows service called "**VMware Authorization Service**" and you need to take care of other software/services like that.
Actually, it worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You will follow some steps:

1. In the search in the bottom just type `uac`.
2. You will find something called "Always Notify"
3. From Notify make it very low "In The Bottom"
4. In some computers maybe the computer want to restart

Then everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to start > type search box `uac` press <kbd>enter</kbd> > you will see 'Change user account control settings' > down the you will see never notify. Click on OK. And you are done.

Answer (score 1):

On my case this dialog box is also showing and Xampp was not working on my computer. But i have just run as administrator and the problem is gone..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).