# xampp installation UAC error is occuring

Tags: php, xampp, uac

I want to install latest version of xampp but while installing this is giving me an error for UAC , I have disabled (in windows) still error is not solved, xampp gets installed but Apache does not start to work where as mysql starts execution, i have changed port number as well in case to solve the issue but issue is not getting solved.
for better understanding i have attached some images.
error message to disable UAC and i have disabled that too from command msconfig and UAC settings.
I have changed port number as well but still didn't got the solution.
[please check the image to get to know about error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3FdC.png)

Comment: What happens if you run XAMPP as administrator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to work on UAC when installing XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26360774/how-to-work-on-uac-when-installing-xampp)

Comment: running as administrator also cause the same issue