# Xammp functions are restricted due to UAC win10. How to fix it?

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-10, uac

I'm trying to install xampp (xampp-win32-7.0.0-0-VC14-installer) but I get this warning message saying that "Because an activated UAC on your system, some functions of XAMPP are possibly restricted..."

Here is xamp warning message screenshot:

[image]

Although I have already disabled UAC settings and gave permission to C drive and its subfolders, I still get this message.

Here is my UAC settings's screenshot:

[image]

If anyone could help me to fix this problem, I would appriciate.

Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Moving the slider down doesn't completely disable UAC since Windows 8. This is changed compared to Windows 7, because the new Store apps require an active UAC. With UAC off, they no longer run.

Do what is suggested and install xampp to `C:\xampp` and not into `program files`.

Answer (score 4):

In order to disable UAC and install XAMPP, go to Registry Editor and navigate to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

[image: Registry Editor]

Right click EnableLUA and modify the Value data to 0.

[image: EnableLUA]

Then restart your computer and you're ready to install XAMPP

[image: Installing XAMPP]

[image: XAMPP installed]

[image: XAMPP Control Panel]

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, just gone through the same error and this solved.

Comment: This solved my error too. Thank you.