# mysql stuck to "Attempting to start MySQL service..."

Tags: mysql

I am installing xampp on my laptop, while installing it gives me a message

[image]

and mysql is not working.. what happen to that?

Comment: install with different drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP installation on Win 8.1 with UAC Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208848/xampp-installation-on-win-8-1-with-uac-warning)