# What is the solution for UAC restricts XAMPP, Apache & MySQL don't start for error?

Tags: xampp, uac

When I clicked the setup file of XAMPP, a warning showed saying User Account Control(UAC) restricts XAMPP... It also happened after I turned off Real-time Protection under Virus and Threat protection of Windows Security, and also after I set the slider of UAC settings to never notify. Also, I uninstalled Skype.

[Real-time Protection turned off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE0LH.png)

[UAC settings slider is set to never notify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgf2t.png)

[UAC restricts XAMPP...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1kmN.png)

During the first installation, a warning showed from Windows Firewall with checkboxes for private and public accesses. But it didn't show up during the next installations after I uninstalled XAMPP. I don't remember whether I checked the two boxes or not.

After installation, I run the XAMPP control panel. When I click Start for either Apache or MySQL, it is said that something is not found... and I click OK 4 times. And the XAMPP control panel shows Apache/MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.

[File not found and Apache/MySQL shutdown...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCZVP.png)

I also tried changing 80 to 8080 in some files while watching some answers from this website but they didn't solve my problems.

How to solve the problems, and why the checkboxes for private and public networks don't come?

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for turning off UAC settings in the link [Solution for XAMPP installation showing UAC warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26208848/).
It only solved the first problem. Before installation, the UAC warning doesn't come now. But after launching the XAMPP control panel, there are red cross icons on the left to Apache, MySQL, FileZilla, and Tomcat. And when I click Start, the previously mentioned box come. And I click OK 4 times. Then these are shown in the panel:

2:43:13 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.

2:43:13 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,

2:43:13 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.

[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heQzv.png)

Finally, I got the solution here [Solution for "VCOMP110.dll was not found" error](https://www.epicgames.com/help/en-US/epic-games-store-c5719341124379/launcher-support-c5719357217435/how-do-i-fix-the-vcruntime140-dll-is-missing-or-vcomp110-dll-was-not-found-error-a5720252258587) But completely following the link didn't solved it. When I clicked the setup file for Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable x64, it was said that I have already installed a version of that. Then when I went to uninstall programmes from the control panel and double-clicked Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable x64, there was an option for uninstalling, and another option for repairing. I clicked Repair. I also did the same process for the x86 one. Then, I restarted the PC, launched XAMPP Control Panel, and clicked Start and Start Alhamdulillaah.
All the praise be to Allaah.